# Como marcar/avisar que um método é obsoleto

Tags: c#

Já notei várias vezes alguns avisos no Visual Studio sobre métodos obsoletos de alguns componentes/bibliotecas:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como por exemplo deixar o método abaixo obsoleto:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="a"></param>
    /// <exception cref=""></exception>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public string MeuMetodo(string a)
    {
        return a;
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Só usar o atributo [**`Obsolete`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/22kk2b44(v=vs.90).aspx).

Também é possível passar como primeiro parâmetro uma mensagem personalizada para o *warning* e como segundo parâmetro um `boolean` que define se o uso deste método vai apenas gerar um *warning* ou **um erro**.

Exemplo

```
public static class Classe
{
    [Obsolete("Use o novo método")]
    public static void MeuMetodo(string a) { }

    [Obsolete("Use o novo método", true)]
    public static void OutroMetodo(string a) { }
}
```

No uso

```
Classe.MeuMetodo("A");
// Gera um warning "Use o novo método"

Classe.OutroMetodo("B");
// Gera um erro e interrompe a compilação
```

Comment: Nossa! Só? Valeu